# CURL call from my webserver does not work however it works from the localhhost and a ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rest, curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49000/xxxx/Execute/xxxxx.B2B_xxx/xxxx111?offset=1&limit=2');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_error($ch))
  {
    echo 'error:' .curl_errno($ch)."--".curl_error($ch);
  }

curl_close($ch);
```

the above code works through my localhost/wamp
However if I upload it to my webserver(linux) I get a **error:7--couldn't connect to host**

but if I do a ajax call from localhost or my web server it works (code below)

```
 $.ajax({                                
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49000/xxxx/Execute/xxxxx.B2B_xxx/xxxx111?offset=1&limit=2",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Loading api success");
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
```

notice the extra **https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/** - if this is not added on to the ajax code url it does not work ... if it is added to the curl url it still does not work.

can some one please help me to understand why this is happening ? been looking around trying a variety of header requests but none seem to work...

Comment: isn't the `49000` port blocked on your webserver or something like that?

Comment: Does your server allow you opening remote file? Check the server setting `allow_url_fopen` is enabled or not.

Comment: Is it possible the remote host is blocking the IPs of your hosted server? It might happen if you're using a hosting service with a not so good reputation

Comment: @ildflue yes thats allowed ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);

Comment: @El_Matella how do i find that out.. plus i am accessing a remote hosts port 49000 not sending my request through that ...

Comment: you can use function `phpinfo()` to get the server side settings of PHP. or just write several line code of using such as `fopen` to make a simple test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check on your server configuration, if you have access to ssh / terminal try run this code

```
dig cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com
```

if it return an error, it mean you need to setup your server DNS, try this:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Put this lines:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

then save it ctrl+o, ctrl-x and test again with dig to check domain resolver.

and make sure that you not connect to local ip like 192.168.x.x, if you connect to local ip from your Linux server then it will never work with curl, but it work on local or ajax because you in the same local network.